# How to add icons in os x status bar menus (left from text)

Tags: objective-c, macos, statusbar

I want to add icons on the left side of my status bar menus text in OS X. I cannot find a sample code to implement this in my code. Right now i am using the code to set the image for the status bar (below) and IBActions to call AppleScript files.

```
    - (void)awakeFromNib {

    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    statusImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"wifi1" ofType:@"png"]];
    statusHighlightImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"wifi2" ofType:@"png"]];

    [statusItem setImage:statusImage];
    [statusItem setAlternateImage:statusHighlightImage];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [statusImage release];
    [statusHighlightImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)RemoteAppleEvents:(id)sender {

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppleEvents" ofType:@"scpt"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
    [appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
    [appleScript release];
}

- (IBAction)InternetSharing:(id)sender {

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WiFiShare" ofType:@"scpt"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
    [appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
    [appleScript release];
}

- (IBAction)BluetoothSharing:(id)sender {

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluetooth" ofType:@"scpt"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
    [appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
    [appleScript release];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanx!

UPDATE*

My drop down menu in IB

[image: My drop down menu in IB].

Comment: I have added a code example to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer:

To set a icon in a NSMenuitem or NSMenu like this:

[image]

You simply have to add an image to your project and set the menus image in the "Attribute Inspector"

[image]

If you want to set the image programatically:

Give each Menu item a outlet  and then use the

setImage:

As you have done for the Status bar

```
 bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
statusItem =  [bar statusItemWithLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength]  ; 

statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"status.icns"];




statusHighlightImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"statusHighLight.icns"];

[statusItem setImage:statusImage];
[statusItem setAlternateImage:statusHighlightImage];

[statusItem setMenu:_statusMenu];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

menu1Image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"login.icns"];
menu2Image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"persist.icns"];
menu3Image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"thumbIcon_.png"];

[_MenuItem1 setImage:menu1Image];
[_MenuItem2 setImage:menu2Image];
[_MenuItem3 setImage:menu3Image];
```

[image]

Also  my code take into account [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! NSViews sounds too complicated for me. I am not sure i understood how i am supposed to use the setAttributedTitle to set the image in the status bar menu. I saw your example but thats for icons in the status bar. I want to implement icons in the menu window like for example the flags in the language menu in os x.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood. First it should have been setTitle: not setAttributedTitle. typo. I have done what you are after but a while back let me see if I can find it..

Comment: Ok so what you want is simple. But what confessed me is you do not have any menu items in your example. Do you actually have any menu items dropping down drown the status menu. Can you update your question with a screen shot

Comment: I cannot post images until i have 10 up votes :-/ I will add the whole code to my original post, so you can see how i call the applescripts.

Comment: I upped an image too. Click on the link. I hope it now makes more sense. :-)

Comment: I have added your image to your question. And updated my answer. But if it does not meet you question. Then can you add as much detail as possible to your answer of your setup and what you have and what you want.

Comment: Oh my... it was that simple really! Yes the attribute inspector did the trick just fine. Very useful to also know how to do this with code also. Awesome help m8... thanx a lot!